# I can't find EJS2 from Package Control

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, ejs, sublimetext

I have been trying to install EJS2 on Sublime Text.

I have installed Package Control.

I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then type `ejs` but no EJS2 installation options appeared.

How can I install the EJS2 package on Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the installation command in the palette first. Here's how you install EJS2:

1. Open the command palette with <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Type `install`, and select the option that says `Package Control: Install Package`. (There may be a wait here depending on your internet connection).
3. Type in the name of the package (`EJS2`) and select the package.
4. Wait until the lower left corner says `Package EJS2 successfully installed`.

That's it! Now EJS2 is installed.

Comment: Dear Jack Bashford It worked! Thank you so much. I didn't do type "install" and click Package Control: Install Package that's why. Thank you very much again.